# Interpreting width in the confidence intervals of an effect size?

Tags: confidence-interval, effect-size, cramers-v

I've calculated an effect size (Cramer's V) with the associated 95% CIs for some analyses I ran. I know that narrow CIs are preferable, but I haven't a clue what constitutes narrow or wide. I understand it's very context dependent for a statistic, but what about a Cramer's V? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the absence of an objective criterion people usually compare it to what other researchers in their field have achieved.

Comment: @mdewey Thank you for the answer. Can I compare mine to the CIs of any effect size measurement or do I have to restrict this to other Cramer's Vs?

Comment: Are you conflating Cramer's V with Cohen's D? The latter is usually interpreted as an effect size whereas the former is a non-parametric measure of association between two ordinal variables - although you could certainly input other (continuous or binary or even time to event values).

Comment: Compare like with like, so V with V not anything else.

Comment: There are no widely discussed standard effect sizes for Cramer V, although there are methods to convert a Cohen D to other association measures (Azuero 2016), which you could certainly do for the Cramer V.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two schools in science. One reports results as-is and leaves the reader to react as befits themselves. The other has the writer go to great lengths to impel their interpretation of the results upon the reader. There have been major efforts to move statisticians away from just reporting $p$-values and reporting CIs instead which, while on the whole has been good for science, introduces the above dilemma.

I am of the opinion that the CI width is not something to "interpret".

WLOG, the width of the CI is a function of three things:

- The level of the CI itself
- The sample size
- The actual sampling distribution of the response

This is the case for *any* statistic - an OLS slope, a hazard ratio, a Pearson correlation, etc. Cramer's V is not unique in this way.

It's not completely clear what your study is.

To reign in the question, we can pretend studies are done for one of two reasons - to compare to a true null, or to compare to other studies. For a true null comparison, you should in fact compute the $p$-value and call it done. The CI contains almost all the same information, but we report it anyway. It may facilitate meta-analysis down the road. To compare to other studies, the CI width doesn't really matter. There is no requirement to replicate exactly points 1 and 2 above to evaluate the consistency of a study. There are meta-analytic approaches to evaluating the homogeneity of two or more studies. If a bogus trial contains egregiously fabricated results, I can do a consistency study of even 10 subjects to prove them wrong - it depends how wrong the other studies are. On the other hand, no sample size can ensure the consistency of two studies, a large enough replication trial will *always* conclude the original trial was false. My CI width can be a mile wide, but if it doesn't overlap the original trial finding, we know there's a major problem.